# how to start a new session in a shell script in platforms other than Linux?

Tags: shell, session, aix

I have this problem:
I have a script A, and it calls another script B, but this script B must run in another session,  it is an easy job to do in a C program with setsid
(), but I cannot find an equivalent shell command. There is a setsid shell
command in Linux, but there are no such commands in AIX and other UNIX
platforms. Can anyone give me some advice on how to do it in AIX and other UNIX platforms? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [setsid()](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/2/setsid/) system call exists in FreeBSD and OpenSolaris, and is part of POSIX.1.  So I would think that it *should* exist in anything that claims to be POSIX-compliant.

AIX is fully compliant with "one or more" of the POSIX standards, but I've never used it, so I can't comment on it directly.  Since it's a vendor-supported operating system, I recommend you touch base with your vendor.

Now..  What do you mean by "an equivalent shell command"?  What do you mean by "session" in the context of a shell script?  If what you're looking for is a way to run a second shell script with a separate controlling terminal from the original script, I suggest you look at [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) instead of system calls.  Screen should be available for AIX.

If you have a shell script that currently works for you in Linux, and you're trying to port it to other platforms, then include the script in your question.  Otherwise, we're flying blind.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I used shell command "setsid" to start a new session in shell script, but OS like AIX and non-Linuxs don't have this command, i.e. "setsid", so how can I get this script run on AIX and other UNIX platforms that don't have shell command "setsid"? thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only thing that /usr/bin/setsid does in linux is run a program detached from the controlling terminal.  Sort of like backgrounding a program by running it with `nohup` and putting a `&` at the end of your command line, then closing your terminal.  Rather than looking for a way to duplicate this functionality, let's look at your original problem and figure out a way to solve that.  Why do you think you need `setsid`?

Comment: our project is shell script, in which we call krenew (kerberos cmd) at certain point, but since krenew and calling script belong to the same process group, we got a lot of error messages(why this happens is unclear,but it is the "same group" thing produce this),To get rid of these messages, I should start the krenew in a new session as a session/group leader. It is an easy job to do in a C program with setsid(), but I cannot find an equivalent shell command. There is a setsid shell command in Linux, but there are no such commands in AIX and other UNIX platforms.
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Alternately, if you just want to ignore error messages that krenew sends to standard out, you can redirect those messages using standard shell redirection.  `krenew -options 2> /dev/null`  It's always better to get help solving your problem rather than get help making the wrong solution work.